# how to post json array using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have to post three parameters on the server using Volley.

1) appointment_id

2) visit_medicines

3) medicines (json medicine ids e.g [1,2,4])

here is my code

```
  Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  params.put("appointment_id", "" + appointment_id);
  params.put("visit_notes", "sdssdsd");
  params.put("medicines", "1");
  getInstance().HttpPOSTRequestWithParameters(getApplicationContext(), ADD_PRESCRIPTION_API, params,AddPriscriptions.this);
```

By above code all things posted except medicines (empty array of medincies returns from the server). its means I am posting in a wrong way to server.

I am confused how to post JSON array as I have to post [1,2,4] to the server. The suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the receive type of the hashmap is `<String, String>`, try convert your JSON array into a string, then put it in the params hashmap

like this

```
params.put("medicines", "[1,2,4]");
```